# Read SAS data into Python

Tags: python

I am tying to read SAS dataset using Python but this is showing an error:

> "IndexError list assignment index out of range"

I am not sure what could be the reason. Can anyone help me out?

Following is the code where I am trying to read SAS data (which is in multi millions) into Python:

```
import pandas as pd  
import numpy as np
from sas7bdat import SAS7BDAT

with SAS7BDAT('/dat_xyz/mdpqr/data_test.sas7bdat') as m:
   mdata = m.to_data_frame()
```

Let me know the solution.

Thanks,
Surya

Comment: could you put the datafile somewhere where it will be publicly accessible and put a link here, so that other users could reproduce the problem?

Comment: Like @DmitriChubarov said please put the datafile up for us to see. In addition  have you tried saving the SAS data file as a CSV/Excel file and see if it is a file type error?